# Puppet can't use config set server

Tags: puppet

I've installed Puppet *(version 4.10.1)* via Ruby Gems.

I then use:

```
sudo puppet config set server mysite.org
```

Which returns the following error (same error without `sudo`).

> Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf Error: Try 'puppet
>   help config set' for usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what led to the situation of the `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet` folder not being created during the install process.

I found creating the folder manually with `sudo mkdir /etc/pupppetlabs/puppet` before running `sudo puppet config set server mysite.org` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The gem install does not create the configuration files, the packages will.

Puppet is best installed with a package for the operating system you're on, rather than the gem.

The steps for installing are documented here:

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/install_linux.html

If you're feeling lazy, I even wrote a script that will do all the work for you!

https://github.com/petems/puppet-install-shell

Comment: Puppet version 4 wasn't available on the OS of the device Ubuntu 14.04. Also I found many solutions didn't work because we're running an embedded ARM device. The Puppet Gem seems to work well for portability.